# MondoDb aggregate for all key in nested field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, backend

I have a collection as:

```
{ 
   userId: ObjectId("..."),
   action: {
             type: "predefined value",
             key1: "key1Value",
             key2: "key2Value",
             key3: "key3Value"
           }
},{ 
   userId: ObjectId("..."),
   action: {
             type: "predefined value",
             key1: "key1aValue"
           }
},
{ 
   userId: ObjectId("..."),
   action: {
             type: "predefined value",
             key3: "key3Value",
             key4: "key4Value"
           }
}
```

By aggregating to the first stage I make a match for the requested userId and I can count the values ​​of a specific key.

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'userId': new ObjectId('62e3aa7cd4524678b541f4fc')
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$action.key1', 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This way I get this ouput

```
[
  {_id: "key1Value", count: 1},
  {_id: "key1aValue", count: 1}
]
```

How can I get through a single aggregate the count of values ​​for each single key as in the output below?

```
[
  key1: [
         {_id: "key1Value", count: 1},
         {_id: "key1aValue", count: 1}
        ],
  key2: [
         ...
        ],
  key3: [
         ...
        ],
  ....
]
```

Comment: if we know that we can have for example key1,key2,key3,key4 known keys, its easy to do   it, else you have to do complicated and slow things like objectToArray, arrayToObject etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some structure manipulation to make this happens, here is an approach using `$objectToArray` to convert the actions object to an array, at that point we can `$unwind` it and `$group` accordingly.

Your requested output is not a valid json so I had to guesstimate what you meant:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      actionsArr: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            "$objectToArray": "$action"
          },
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$this.k",
              "type"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$actionsArr"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        key: "$actionsArr.k",
        value: "$actionsArr.v"
      },
      sum: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.key",
      values: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id.value",
          count: "$sum"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [
          [
            {
              k: "$_id",
              v: "$values"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F-rPi5ehs6z)